# Pycharm is supposed to support Anaconda but does not appear to

Tags: windows, installation, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying to get PyCharm 2017.2.3 Community working nicely with Anaconda on my windows 7 box (64 bit).

According to [the jetbrains docs for PyCharm and Conda](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-environment.html) when I open the Project Interpreters page, I should see a "Create Conda Env" option.

That "Create Conda Env" option does not appear, only "Add Local" and "Create VirtualEnv". Has anyone managed to get this PyCharm/Conda integration working and have some ideas why it doesn't work on my box?

For what it's worth, I can create an environment manually in PyCharm, but there seem to be issues with this compared to my conda env (some imports not working etc), so I'm keen to get the native integration working if possible.

PyCharm is aware that I have a python installation as it gives me the option of selecting the python interpreter under my Anaconda folder. It just doesn't seem to recognise it specifically as Anaconda wrt creating PyCharm environments.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed after I reinstalled windows without setting some key directories away from my c:\ drive. I had initially set things up to try and default to installing programs on my d:\ drive instead, because my c:\ SSD was so limited in space, and it appears changing these registry settings is what broke PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue.

Here is how I solve it.

First , I ensure I can use lib in anaconda in pycharm.

then , I type 'conda' in cmd, it is not an internal order.Can't run conda.

So ,I can use anaconda in pycharm but still system can't run it.

I check my System path, and anaconda is already there.

I restart.

I reinstall and this time I specify a document instead of the default invisible one.

I didn't click two options while installing.

I run Anaconda Navigator in Win so it will change my anaconda path for me.(As install program told me to)

Then I run conda in cmd.

It react.

Then I check my pycharm:
[image]